# Asp.net mvc passing a C# model to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I want to pass the value i got it from model to the java-script function

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var checkin = @Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        var checkout = @Model.Parameters.Checkout.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        
 </script>
```

this function that i want to pass model chick-in and chick-out value  to it:

```
$('document').ready(function () {       

   $("#Arrival").val(checkin);
  $("#Departure").val(checkout); 
 });
```

i tried many solution but it didn't work yet .
any advice, thanks

Comment: if the @Model has value try `checkin = '@Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")';`

Comment: inside the script var obj = '@(Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))'

Comment: @AsifRaza i replaced still not working , i get the value from model inside script in the view.cshtml but inside js.file i can not get the value from the model ?

Comment: '@(Model.Parameters.Checkin)' try this one , and make sure are you getting value inside Parameter.Checkin ?

Comment: @AsifRaza Now , when i tried to put your line inside $('document').ready(function () { });  function i can not get the value it gives me this line @(Model.Parameters.Checkin) but if set it the view.chtml i get the value correctly ??

Comment: '@(Model.Parameters.Checkin)' with single quotation. can you please post your model ?

Comment: $('document').ready(function () { }...... To $(document).ready(function () {} Place your code inside the document ready method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if the `@Model.Parameters.Checkin` and `@Model.Parameters.Checkout` not `null` then Try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function(){       
 var checkin = '@Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")';
 var checkout = '@Model.Parameters.Checkout.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")';

   $("#Arrival").val(checkin);
  $("#Departure").val(checkout); 
 });
```

Just you miss `'`.  and also change `$('document').ready(function () { })` to     `$(document).ready(function () { })`.

you must write all `script` into a `.cshtml` file. `@Model.Parameters.Checkin.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` never work into a `.js` file.

Because, In `.cshtml`, when the the page is render then it white to HTTP response stream as a string.

Comment: Best practices say you should not mix C# and Javascript. I think you should pass your model in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you can use following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = parseInt(@ViewBag.Number); //Accessing the number from the ViewBag
    alert("Number is: " + number);
    var model = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.FooObj); //Accessing the Json Object from ViewBag
    alert("Text is: " + model.Text);
</script>
```